# How to bind a query with a join to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, linq-to-entities, ado.net-entity-data-model

Right now, I have created a new Object data source based off from an Object Context from the entity model. I then created a BindingSource and a DataGridView set to this BindingSource.

I can add columns which are bound to the data from the TraceLine table. When I set the DataSource, I see values in those columns. However, I can’t seem to get the data from the joined table. How do I bind a DataGridView to a query that has a join?

```
using (var entities = new MyEntities())
{
    var lines = from t in entities.Lines
                join m in entities.Methods on t.MethodHash equals m.MethodHash
                where t.UserSessionProcessId == m_SessionId
                select new
                {
                    m.Name,  // doesn't get displayed in DataGridView, but I want it to
                    t.Sequence,
                    t.InclusiveDuration,
                    t.ExclusiveDuration
                };

    dgvBindingSource.DataSource = lines;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible issue is that the DataGridView may have its DataSource set at design time to one of the types but at runtime you're setting it to an anonymous type that has an extra member. If I recall, DataGridView won't re-generate the columns if you change the data source after columns have been generated.

You may need to set the data source to null, clear the column collection, then set the data source. In fact a better idea would be to create the columns explicitly instead of auto generating them.

Comment: Just curious if you are suggesting to not use the data binding, add the columns manually, then iterate through the collection and fill in the datagridview manually? I know that this is an option, but was the last resort.

Comment: No no... data binding is fine. But the DataGridView, like most grids, will automatically build out the columns by reflecting against the data source. But if you have a design time binding against one of the types that make up your anonymous type, you may need to add the column manually. The values in the cells should data bind as expected.