# How do you bind a linq-to-entities query that contains a join to a writable datagridview?

Tags: data-binding, datagridview, linq-to-entities, denormalization

This question, although [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460599/binding-linq-to-entities-query-results-to-a-datagridview) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090552/how-to-bind-a-query-with-a-join-to-a-datagridview) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393223/binding-linq-query-to-datagridview), doesn't seem to be a duplicate. If it is, please clarify and I will be happy to merge.

I want to bind to a writable DataGridView using a linq-to-entities query containing a join. The model is as follows:

[image]

The denormalized DataGridView should be bound like so:

[image]

The following code binds but results in a readonly DataGridView because the linq-to-entities query returns an anonymous type ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460599/binding-linq-to-entities-query-results-to-a-datagridview)). I'm at an impasse because I think I need the anonymous type to do the denormalization.

```
var query = from t in iDictionaryContext.DisplayTexts
        from l in iDictionaryContext.Languages
        where
            t.LanguageID == l.LanguageID
        select new
         {
             Key = t.DisplayKey,
             Text = t.DisplayText1,
             Language = l.LanguageName
         };
```

I also tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065627/binding-datagridview-to-a-multiple-table-linq-to-sql-query) but it seems to apply to linq-to-sql but not to linq-to-entities. When setting the bindingsource.datasource to the linq-to-entities query, an exception is thrown reading "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Thank you for your advice,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define presentation type like that. You don't have to pass objects in constructor:

```
public class LanguageDisplayTextPresentation 
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
var query = from t in iDictionaryContext.DisplayTexts
    from l in iDictionaryContext.Languages
    where
        t.LanguageID == l.LanguageID
    select new LanguageDisplayTextPresentation 
    {
        Key = t.DisplayKey,
        Text = t.DisplayText1,
        Language = l.LanguageName
    };
```

Comment: Although this will make the DataGridView editable, this won't update the entities, will it? And how about adding/deleting rows?